# Using custom django model in DRF Token Authentication

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I want to connect a custom User model with the Django Rest Framework TokenAuthentication module. I have tried the followings:

```
settings.py:

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'myapp.authentication.MyOwnTokenAuthentication',
     ),
}
```

```
authentication.py:

class MyOwnTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    model = MyOwnToken
```

```
models.py:

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    birth = models.DateField()

class MyOwnToken(models.Model):

    key = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, primary_key=True)

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, related_name='auth_token',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User"
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)
```

```
views.py:

class UserApi(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [MyOwnTokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    #returns all data 
    def get(self, request):
        alldata=User.objects.all()
        alldata_serialized=UserSerializer(alldata, many=True)
        return Response(alldata_serialized.data)
```

The token generates fine but when I call the UserApi get then it gives WrappedAttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'

can anyone help??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Added 'is_active' column to the user table and set to True.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    birth = models.DateField()
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and removed the

```
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

from the views.py and it works fine.